# How to auto add header to iframe in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, http-headers

I have an app, and I want to show an iframe to another site. The problem is that site is made to only work if it has an `Authorization` header attached to it. Not only for the main page, but all its static assets too.

Question is, is there a way to load iframe, but to program it to auto intercept, inject and load the authorization header for the main source link and all its assets?

Thanks